# Attachment not sent from Server while Locally work's perfectly

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Actually i'm trying to send via ASPX using VB.NET as language a mail with attachment that user put in the form via FileUpload which i save to a folder.
All works fine the file is saved and the mail is sent with attachment when i run the site Locally but on the server if i attach something the file is just saved but the email is not sent.

Here is the code where i add the attachment to the mail.

```
  Dim Message As New MailMessage()
        Message.To.Add(New MailAddress(reparto))
        Message.Subject = oggetto
        Message.IsBodyHtml = True
        Message.Body =
                       "<p><h3> " + prodotto + " </h3><br /> " +
                       "Richiesta di assistenza per il seguente motivo: " + descr +
                       " <br /> " +
                       " <br /> " +
                       " <b>Email cliente: " + email + " </b></p>" +
                       image.ToString


        If FileUpload.HasFiles Then
            For Each postedFile As HttpPostedFile In FileUpload.PostedFiles
                Dim data As Attachment = New Attachment(Server.MapPath("~/images/") + postedFile.FileName, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet)
                Message.Attachments.Add(data)
                'image.Append("<img src=" + """" + (Server.MapPath("~/images/") + postedFile.FileName + """" + "/>"))
            Next
        End If


        Dim client As New SmtpClient()

        Try
            client.Send(Message)
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' ...
        End Try
```

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the read access on the directory where the attachment is sitting. You don't get any errors in the server / event viewer.

Comment: @Chuck no i don't and actually i gave all access to the folder where the images / files are placed